Configure terraform to create custom Azure Entra ID App registration for SAML SSO
In EntraID I have a hand crafted App registion using

Application ID URI : https://api-my.tugboatlogic.com/saml/org/.../metadata

Via the console I did the following

browse Entra app galery
create your own application
Integrate any other application you don't find in the gallery (Non-gallery)

This resulted in an Enterprise application where I could configure SSO SAML and claims, using non AZure URLS for identifier and reply urls
When I try to do this in terraform, I'm using the following and getting an error that the URIs must be within my org doamin/subdomain.
I'm clearly not approaching the problem properly but I can't see how to do the terraform equivalent of the above manual procedure
Error
unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error:
HostNameNotOnVerifiedDomain: Values of identifierUris property must use a
verified domain of the organization or its subdomain:


Code
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  display_name = var.app_name
  tags         = local.tags_flat

  identifier_uris = [var.identifier_url]

  web {
    redirect_uris = [var.reply_url]
    logout_url  = var.logout_url
  }
}

Related

Using data lookup for service_principal


Are you still facing the issue. @Peter Kahn

I'm no longer working on this project but yes, I never resolved it
